# How to pass multiple files for same input parameter in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, input

I have two input files, and I need to pass both the files under the same parameter in Hadoop.

```
EG: hadoop jar somemainclass -D testInput=file1,file2
```

I don't want to combine the files into one file is used based on some user condition. 
I  tried giving the parameter -D testInput twice, but it took only the last file and not the first file.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass multiple instances of the same parameter, then the value of the first instance is going to be overwritten by the value of the second instance.

You can specify multiple values for the same parameter, by separating the values with commas.

For e.g.

```
<property>
   <name>yarn.resourcemanager.zk-address</name>
   <value>zk1:2181,zk2:2181,zk3:2181</value>
 </property>
```

So, while passing the values through command line, you can specify -DtestInput=file,file2

Comment: I am passing put to the file as ` -D hdfs://<namenode>/path/to/file1,hdfs://<namenode>/path/to/file2 `but i am getting error  as below                                                                             ```file1,hdfs:/<namenode>file2is not a valid DFS filename. (kindly note the single '/' after hdfs in the second file )
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getPathName(DistributedFileSystem.java:196)`

Comment: You don't have to pass the paths as hdfs://<namenode>/path/to/fille1. You can simply pass -DtestInput=/path/to/fille1,/path/to/file2"

Comment: There is a catch for me. We have an edge node and the HDFS file directory system is exact replica of NAS to which edge node is connecting to. If I am not specifying the hdfs://namenode  it is reading from NAS instead of HDFS

Comment: I am bit surprised. Have you set the DefaultFileSystem as HDFS? Then it should always treat these paths as HDFS paths. When you use "hdfs://", the "isValidName()" function of DFSUtilClient.java, returns error. The description of this function reads: "Whether the pathname is valid. Currently prohibits relative paths, names which contain a ":" or "//", or other non-canonical paths." So, it does not allow paths containing ":" or "//".

Comment: I just checked the core-site.xml file in my cluster and it does indeed point to hdfs.